# MCP609 op-amp is not powered in this circuit. It is normal?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I've just finished soldering and i'm about to test the circuit and see how it goes.
Instead of **MCP609**, i used two **MCP602** and I noticed that **Vss** and **Vdd** pins are not connected to the power supply.
Does these opamps work without beign powered in a circuit like this?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Of course not, it is implicitly assumed to be properly powered.

Comment: *I noticed that Vss and Vdd pins are not connected to the power supply.* What power supply? There isn't any supply drawn in this schematic because all those supply lines would make the schematic very cluttered. Of course all ICs need a power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does these opamps work without beign powered in a circuit like this?

No.  Of course not.  Why do you think they have power pins?  Do you think the PIC12C508 shown in the upper right also works with only a single wire connected to it?

Opamps are often shown in schematics without their power and ground connections right at the opamp triangle symbol.  That is because these can get in the way of understanding the use of the opamp and the circuit around it.

Also consider how you would draw the power connections for something like a quad opamp.  Do you make one of the four separate opamps a special symbol to show the power connections to the whole chip?  That would be awkward.

The typical solution is to use a separate symbol for the power connections to the opamp chip, just like the multiple amps in a quad opamp are separate symbols.  This power block is then usually off in a corner somewhere, showing what power is connected to the V+ and V- pins, the bypass caps, perhaps power filtering, etc.

The schematic you show doesn't include such a block.  Maybe that's because it's not a full schematic and is part block diagram.  Again, note the PIC with a single connection to it.  Or, maybe the opamp power connections are shown on a different page.

Answer (score -1):

> Does these opamps work without beign powered in a circuit like this?

No. What you see is a circuit diagram where the power connections are not shown. In the CAD-system there will be 'hidden' connections of the power pins to pre-defined voltage, like 5V or VCC, GND.
If you transfer this to a PCB lay-out tool those connections and the net names will suddenly appear.
I think it is a very bad system and I am tempted to fire any designer who uses it.

Comment: You'd fire someone for making a schematic easy to understand?

Comment: For making a 'misleading' schematic but even more for not understanding that power pins are very, very important. Not some afterthought which can be mostly ignored. The power pins should be drawn or should be added as a separate power block. Preferable on the same page as the component. Then the appropriate decoupling should be next to it, making a clear what power pins and what decoupling go together.

Comment: this is an overview diagram, not a schematic meant for layouting. Same goes e.g. for chemical structure formulas, where often carbon atoms are left out because "any competent reader can infer there's a C where multiple lines meet". Just as "any competent reader" knows that you need to power an opamp. @Finbarr is absolutely right, not having the power pins here makes the circuit *better*, not worse.